# SQL Rows into columns with unique column names

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data:

```
Id  RaceId  Position    Letter_v_Letter Number  Letter  Letter_Number
1   1       1           H-C HARD        5       C HARD  C HARD5
2   1       2           J-D             3       D       D3
3   1       3           D               8       D       D8
```

I need to return a single row [RaceId] with columns 1 to 3 for each of the Letter_v_Letter, Number, Letter and Letter_Number

I have been looking at pivot, union all and cross apply examples on here but cant get the result I need which is:

```
RaceId    Letter_v_Letter_1  Letter_v_Letter_2  Letter_v_Letter_3  Number_1  Number_2  etc.
1         H-C Hard           J-D                D                  5         3
```

I'm using this to create a view from 2 tables to simplify a lookup query

Is it going to be a temp table job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conditional aggregation would do the trick here

```
Select RaceID
      ,Letter_v_Letter_1 = max(case when Position=1 then Letter_v_Letter end)
      ,Letter_v_Letter_2 = max(case when Position=2 then Letter_v_Letter end)
      ,Letter_v_Letter_3 = max(case when Position=3 then Letter_v_Letter end)
      ,Number_1          = max(case when Position=1 then Number end)
      ,Number_2          = max(case when Position=2 then Number end)
      ,Number_3          = max(case when Position=3 then Number end)
      ,Letter_1          = max(case when Position=1 then Letter end)
      ,Letter_2          = max(case when Position=2 then Letter end)
      ,Letter_3          = max(case when Position=3 then Letter end)
      ,Letter_Number_1   = max(case when Position=1 then Letter_Number end)
      ,Letter_Number_2   = max(case when Position=2 then Letter_Number end)
      ,Letter_Number_3   = max(case when Position=3 then Letter_Number end)
 From  YourTable
 Group By RaceID
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: I was about to post a different solution, but this is much more elegant, so upvoted instead!

Comment: @3N1GM4  Funny, I show my wife what I think is cool code, and she just rolls her eyes.  :)

Comment: She would have rolled her eyes more if she'd seen what I was about to post. :)

Comment: @SteveH Happy to help